# For loop troubling for printing multiple values

Tags: java

So the question is:
Write a program that reads a sequence of input values and displays a bar chart of the values using asterisks. You may assume that all values are positive. First figure out the maximum value. That value’s bar should be drawn with 40 asterisks. Shorter bars should use proportionally fewer asterisks. 
eg.

```
***********************
*********
****************************************
****
*******************
```

This is my code below:

```
    int count = 0;
    //Finds largest Value
    int largestValue = numbersArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
        if (numbersArray[i] > largestValue) {
            largestValue = numbersArray[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    //Prints number of asterisks
    final int MAX = 40;
    String asterisks = "****************************************";
    for (int i = 0; i < count + 2; i++) {
        System.out.print(numbersArray[i]);
        if (numbersArray[i] == largestValue) {
            System.out.print(asterisks);
        } //if (numbersArray[i] != largestValue) {
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < (40 * numbersArray[i] / largestValue); j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
  }
```

This code doesn't seem to run properly.
If I enter values in the order: 5 8 6 4 7, it will just print the stars for 5 and 8, and not the rest. Basically it prints stars for values till the largest number.

I can't find what's wrong with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for reading <3

Comment: `numbersArray[i] / largestValue` will do integer division

Comment: @Priyamal Wild guesses are not helpful.  If you don't know, don't guess.

Comment: @ScaryWombat but it's `40 * numbersArray[i] / largestValue`, so the integer division is not the problem (`40 * 6 / 8 == 30` even with integer division)

Comment: @ThomasKläger Yep, not an answer, just a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to `count` variable - it does nothing helpful to you and you for some reason limit yourself (you increment everytime you find a larger element so you only increment once since there's nothing larger than 8).

What you should be doing is finding the largest value, as you did, and then running over the entire array and displaying each element proportional to that value, as you did (but without the special case for the actual largest value - that is atrocious).

Also, you should note that division of two integers would result in an `integer`, which is not what you want, so you'll have to cast one of them to `float` or `double`.

```
//finds largest Value
int largestValue = numbersArray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    if (numbersArray[i] > largestValue) {
        largestValue = numbersArray[i];
    }
}

//Prints number of asterisks
final int MAX = 40;
for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    int portion = (int)(MAX * (numbersArray[i] / (float)largestValue));
    for (int j = 0; j < portion; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

So you'll find the largest value is 8.

Then for 5, you'll do 5/8 which is 0.625 and times `MAX` (40) that would be 25, so you'll print 25 `*`.

Then for 8 - `8/8 = 1.0 * MAX = 40` so you'll print the whole 40 `*`.

For 6 - `6/8 = 0.75 * MAX = 30` so you'll print 30 `*` and so on.

Note that if you want to fine-tune it, you could use `Math.round` instead of simply casting the `portion` to int (which simply truncates the floating point).

Comment: @Ori Lentz Good but I don't see that the (float) cast is needed, provided you don't alter the order of evaluation, by using parentheses, as you did. 40 * 5 / 8 is still 25. And, you wouldn't need to cast the result to int, either.

Comment: @TonyWeddle it's needed only because I wrapped the division in parenthesis in order to clarify the process / computation. In you example, first the multiplication is taken, which is why it works (i.e. `40 * (5/8) = 0` without a cast).

Comment: @OriLentz nice job man! I looked over your at profile and it says that you've been programming for quite a while now. Can you recommend me some sites where I could learn programming online? I'm very new to Java programming.

Comment: @Burhan Thank you. Can I ask you to accept the answer as well? About tutorials, I don't know any specific ones to recommend, but there must be countless out there. I'd suggest something that puts the emphasis on object-oriented most and foremost in order to truly understand the concepts.

Comment: @OriLentz ok thanks. I'm new to StackOverFlow too so I'm still getting used to it :P

Comment: @Ori Lentz As I wrote, the order of evaluation is changed by the parenthesis. Casting does complicate the code a little, which is why I mentioned it. No parentheses, no casts.